# I am having an issue while retrieving array values on jsp page for dropdown option

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, foreach

I have to get the values from different different table and values are more than one and all values in different different drop down box i have to show on the basis of box , I have done this am not sure my way is correct or not but m getting value but finally what happening when i am trying to select value it is coming but like this [saurabh, prakash, karan] and in one row with array symbol but i want saurabh and in next row prakash so this is my problem, here my servlet class in which i am calling empDetail method

```
 @WebServlet(name = "EmployeeMapping", urlPatterns = {"/EmployeeMapping"})
 public class EmployeeMapping extends HttpServlet {
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);     
  Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
  EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
  List<Employee> leave1 = eb.empDetail(emp1); 
  if(emp1.isValid())
  {
    request.setAttribute("leave1",leave1);
    response.sendRedirect("AssignProject.jsp");
  }}
   @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
   }
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
     }
  @Override
  public String getServletInfo() {
  return "Short description";}}
```

here is my method

```
  public List<Employee> empDetail(Employee emp1) {
  List<Employee> leave1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  List<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> myList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> myList4 = new ArrayList<String>();
  try{
  con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
  stmt1 = con.createStatement();
  String Query11 = "SELECT projectname FROM addproject";
  System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query11);
  rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery(Query11);
  while(rs1.next())
  {
  String z =(rs1.getString("projectname"));
  System.out.println("...11." +z);
  myList1.add(z);
  }
   emp1.setPrjname(myList1);
   stmt2 = con.createStatement();
  String Query12 = "select empName from empinfo where access_type ='teamleader'";
  System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query12);
  rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(Query12);
  while(rs2.next())
  {
String p = rs2.getString("empName");
System.out.println("...11." +p);
myList2.add(p);
  }
  emp1.setTlname(myList2);
  stmt3 = con.createStatement();
  String Query13 = "select empName from empinfo where access_type ='manager'";
  System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query13);
  rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(Query13);
  while(rs3.next())
  {
  String q = rs3.getString("empName");
  System.out.println("...11." +q);
  myList3.add(q);
  }     
  emp1.setManname(myList3);
  stmt4 = con.createStatement();
   String Query14 = "select empName from empinfo where access_type ='employee'";
   System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query14);
   rs4 = stmt4.executeQuery(Query14);
   while(rs4.next())
  {
  String r = rs4.getString("empName");
  System.out.println("...11." +r);
  myList4.add(r);
  }
   emp1.setEmpname(myList4);
   leave1.add(emp1);
   emp1.setValid(true);
  }
  catch (SQLException  ex) {
  } finally {
      try {
          if (pstmt != null) {
              pstmt.close();
          }
          if (con != null) {
              con.close();
          }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(EmployeeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }
    return leave1;
    };
```

here is my jsp page in which i am getting values like [saurabh, prakash, karan] but if i am giving insted of ${emp1.prjname} this ${emp1.prjname[0]} then i am getting saurabh so like wise and here i am facing difficulty t put for loop with this so please any one help me ..

```
 <%if(session.getAttribute("emp1")==null)
 {
 String message ="please login first";
 request.setAttribute("message", message);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }
 %>
   <title>RESOURCE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</title>
 <head
 </head><body>
 <%
 Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
 session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1);
 %>
 <tr>
        <td >select project name </td>
         <td>   <select name="pname">    
      <option value="${emp1.prjnamename}">${emp1.prjnamename}</option></select></td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
      <td >manager </td>
         <td>   <select name="manager">
      <option value="${emp1.manname}">${emp1.manname}</option></select></td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
               <td >team leader</td>
         <td>   <select name="teamleader">
      <option value="emp1.Tlname()">emp1.Tlname()</option></select></td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
                <td> <section class="container">
    <div>
    <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple>
   <option value="${emp1.empname}">${emp1.empname}</option>                  
  </select>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
  </div>
 </td>
  <td>
 <div>
    <select name="nameofemps" id="rightValues" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        <option>
        </option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtRight" />
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 </td>
   </tr>            
        </table><BR>
        </fieldset>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the `forEach` loop with the `request` attribute,

```
  <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple>
  <c:forEach var='temp' items='${leave1}' >
    <option value="${temp.empname}">${temp.empname}</option>    
  </c:forEach>              
  </select>
```

Also , you are creating a new request here,

```
  if(emp1.isValid())
  {
    request.setAttribute("leave1",leave1);
    response.sendRedirect("AssignProject.jsp");
  }}
```

the same request should be `forwarded` to the jsp. Use `RequestDispatcher` instead

<sub>I assume you are trying to print the `leave1` from the request, comment below my answer if your view differs</sub>

Comment: Sir i should put like this  <c:forEach var='temp' items='leave1'  or  <c:forEach var='temp' items='${leave1}'  because without using $ sign its giving error and with dollar page is running but it is coming blank i dont knw why... sir check my code i m not using leave1 vairable to retieve the value i m using just emp1.empname and answer is not coming in rows its coming in single row like [saurabh, prakash,karan].. so sir plz help me..

Comment: sir i got it and i used now  request.getRequestDispatcher("/AssignProject.jsp").forward(request, response); in this case now its not blank but answer is same using ur suggestion values with array in same row but i found solution my own and I have given here..

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of my problem which is

```
          <tr>
         <td >select project name </td>
          td>   <select name="pname">
         <c:forEach var="temp" items="${emp1.prjname}">
         <option value="${temp}">${temp}</option>                  
       </c:forEach></select></td></tr>
```

and its working